# Separate input devices (fullscreen for multiple monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

How can I have fullscreen app on one monitor capturing the output from, say, controller. And at the same time be able to use second monitor with keyboard and mouse in a regular way without minimizing the full screen up on other monitor?